# Windows 7 Music get lowered by game

Tags: windows-7, audio

whenever I play music in the background of a game it seems to lower the sound of music.
Also when im on teamspeak, both the game and music get lowered by teamspeak.
I have already checked the "do nothing" button.
I am using realtek audio hd MSI.
I'm also using sound blaster cinema if that might cause a issue.

Comment: It could have something to do with the SBX Smart Volume setting of the sound blaster cinema... Is it enabled?

Comment: Can't find any setting like that, checked all of the options... http://prntscr.com/5xgrrh

Comment: Press on that waveform kind of icon on the bottom. See this: http://www.easycom.com.ua/data/news/1302271930/img/MSI_Creative_Sound_Blaster_Cinema.jpg

Comment: Yes I think that fixed it! Thanks alot sanjab :)

Comment: Close voters: I don't see how this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has a similar problem. I compile my comments into an answer here:

The solution is to switch off the smart volume setting in the sound blaster cinema settings:

[image]